# Privileges for CREATE table on MySQL, given all privileges

Tags: mysql, privileges, create-table

This is the user privileges:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'LMMXT'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*...'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `LMMXT`.`*` TO 'LMMXT'@'localhost'
```

I can LOGIN with the user, USE Database, but always when I want CREATE TABLE:

```
# mysql -u LMMXT -p -h localhost
mysql> use LMMXT
Database changed
mysql> create table test;
ERROR 1142 (42000): CREATE command denied to user 'LMMXT'@'localhost' for table 'test'
```

And:

```
mysql> SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
+---------------------+---------------------+
| USER()              | CURRENT_USER()      |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| LMMXT@localhost | LMMXT@localhost |
+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, also I've tried with:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

User is set for host access from `'localhost'` and '%'

I've seen other solutions on StackOverflow, but none works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your grant statement to

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON LMMXT.* TO 'LMMXT'@'localhost'
```

I'm not sure if the ` characters around the statement are causing a problem

Comment: it Works!!  Problem was chars ` ` . Thanks